# Cleaning Mixed Geographic Data (R)

Tags: r, nlp, geo

I have a very ugly column in a dataset that contains a mix of States and Cities (domestic and international). The rest of the data is all numbers and nothing correlating to anything geographic. Is there any method to do a text-analysis to determine what is what with the end goal of making columns to separate states and cities and have a 3rd column to show country?

```
   c("Arizona", "(not set)", "Arizona", "(not set)", "California", 
"California", "New York", "Texas", "New York", "Texas", "England", 
"Illinois", "Florida", "Maharashtra", "Massachusetts", "Virginia", 
"Maryland", "Florida", "Karnataka", "Pennsylvania", "Arizona", 
"New Jersey", "Illinois", "District of Columbia", "Delhi", "Ohio", 
"Ontario", "Georgia", "Colorado", "Washington", "Michigan", "Virginia", 
"North Carolina", "England", "Maryland", "Pennsylvania", "Colorado", 
"Utah", "Arizona", "New Jersey", "District of Columbia", "Tamil Nadu", 
"North Carolina", "Arizona", "Massachusetts", "Tokyo", "Andhra Pradesh", 
"Minnesota", "Washington", "Tainan City", "Michigan", "Arizona", 
"Maharashtra", "Federal District", "Ile-de-France", "Utah", "Georgia", 
"Metro Manila", "Ontario", "Connecticut")
```

[image]

Comment: Not a good idea to post image of data. Can you post some data, especially with bad data.

Comment: @ShanR apologizes, made the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how exhaustive you want to search, you can download one or more of the files under https://download.geonames.org/export/dump/ and search one or more of the columns. For the set of test data you gave, I was able to do this:

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://download.geonames.org/export/dump/cities500.zip",temp)
unzipped <- unz(temp, "cities500.txt")
cities500 <- read.delim(unzipped, header=FALSE)

c("Arizona", "(not set)", "Arizona", "(not set)", "California", 
  "California", "New York", "Texas", "New York", "Texas", "England", 
  "Illinois", "Florida", "Maharashtra", "Massachusetts", "Virginia", 
  "Maryland", "Florida", "Karnataka", "Pennsylvania", "Arizona", 
  "New Jersey", "Illinois", "District of Columbia", "Delhi", "Ohio", 
  "Ontario", "Georgia", "Colorado", "Washington", "Michigan", "Virginia", 
  "North Carolina", "England", "Maryland", "Pennsylvania", "Colorado", 
  "Utah", "Arizona", "New Jersey", "District of Columbia", "Tamil Nadu", 
  "North Carolina", "Arizona", "Massachusetts", "Tokyo", "Andhra Pradesh", 
  "Minnesota", "Washington", "Tainan City", "Michigan", "Arizona", 
  "Maharashtra", "Federal District", "Ile-de-France", "Utah", "Georgia", 
  "Metro Manila", "Ontario", "Connecticut") %in% cities500$V2
```

Note that I didn't exhaustively test for your input, just enough to show the possibilities. Since there are multiple dump files in the site and multiple columns in each, you need to experiment and find the right fit.